# Openmeetings: Issue to login in to openmeetings in SSO login from another application

Tags: openmeetings

I am writing code to login in to openmeetings from another application SSO login from another application and want to enter in to room directly by using API.

I tried the following steps:

1. Get the SID by using code below:

   ```
   $.ajax({
     method: "GET",
     url: "http://localhost:5080/openmeetings/services//user/login",
     data: {user: 'amit.k', pass: 'Mind1234'},
     dataType: "json",
     error : function(jqXHR) {
                       console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
                   },
                   success : function(result) {
                       getHashAndEnterRoom(result.serviceResult.message);                                                                
                   }
   });
   ```
2. Get Hash key by using SID from above function and try to enter in room:

   ```
   function getHashAndEnterRoom(sid){

   $.ajax({
         method: "POST",
         url: "http://localhost:5080/openmeetings/services/user/hash?sid="+sid,
         data: {user: JSON.stringify({
             firstname: 'John',
             lastname: 'Doe',
             externalId: 'uid1',
             externalType: 'myCMS',
             login: 'superjohn'
             }),
           options: JSON.stringify({
             roomId: 5,
             moderator: true,
             showAudioVideoTest: true
             })
           },
         dataType: "json",
               error : function(jqXHR) {
                               },
               success : function(result) {

               var url ="http://localhost:5080/openmeetings/swf?secureHash="+result.serviceResult.message+"&;language";

                                OR 

               var url ="http://localhost:5080/openmeetings/swf?secureHash="+result.serviceResult.message+"&;language=1#room/2";
                               window.location=url;
               }
       })
   ```

I got the SID successfully and  Hash key also got successfully but when I try to navigate to URL(window.location) it shows login screen every time.

I am stuck here since few days but did not success s please guide I will be thank full to you.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to connect developer of this, please check below link this seems bug in openmeetings. 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENMEETINGS-1537

I am also struggling for the same. Even I tried to "boomerang google plugin" as described in this issue, but first step is also not going to successful.

Answer (score 0):

Final URL is wrong

```
// Instead of

var url ="http://localhost:5080/openmeetings/swf?secureHash="+result.serviceResult.message+"&;language=1#room/2";

// you should use

var url ="http://localhost:5080/openmeetings/hash?secure="+result.serviceResult.message+"&;language=1#room/2";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by giving username and password of admin role in first call. and change the last redirect url to 
http://localhost:5080/openmeetings/hash?secure=hashcode&language=1